# How to append text to action type and perform submit operation in HTML

Tags: html

I am new to HTML scripting, I am trying to execute a link by taking an argument and perform some action type

For EX: When I execute below code it is executing without any erros

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost:8080/downloads/1312">
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>

</body>
```

Output for this:a,b,c

But in the above case I want to enter `1312` as an input and submit it so that it should give me the same out put which it displayed earlier.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost:8080/downloads/">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name=" " value="">
  <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>

</body>
```

When i enter 1312 in submit button I am getting http://localhost:8080/downloads/?+=1312 instead of http://localhost:8080/downloads/1312

Answer (score 0):

What you want to acomplish is a bit diffetent.
I would suggest you to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL to better understand what a URL is.

As I understand your question, you want the 1312 to be a part of you URL itself, and **not** query parameter, or to include it as form parameter in request body.
If this is the case, i think the simplest way to go would be to use javascript and concat the strings together.
The logic would be something like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form  onsubmit="myFunction(event);" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="myResource">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const myResourceID = event.target.querySelector("[name=myResource]").value;

    event.target.setAttribute("action", "http://localhost:8080/downloads/" + myResourceID);
    event.target.submit();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

you can read about submiting events here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp
I think it will be helpful.

Comment: It should submit via post, for my initial code, when i click on submit button  it gives me values directly. but in my second case I dont want to hard code my last string 1312, I just want to change it based on my use case, that is the reason I want make it as an argument and that argument I want to enter it in  rectangular box and should have a submit button below, when I enter some number 0909 and click on submit button it should display results for 0909,

Comment: try something like the thing in my comment (I edited it).
Hope this helps